# Access 2013 - How to remove Number automatic default in table design

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

I'd like for the Default Value for a Number field in table designer to be blank upon creation rather than 0. I'd found the answer and changed it before years ago, but can't seem to find the info currently for Access 2013.

Comment: Have you tried ""? Two double quotes without a space between them.

Comment: I'm not talking about adding the field and then changing the Default Value to blank, I'm talking about an application setting such that when I add a Number field the Default Value is already blank and I don't have to change it.

Answer (score 3):

The only way to arrange this is setting the default value to Null in the corresponding table.
There's no such thing as an application setting that will arrange this for numeric fields.

Comment: He'd like to change it to a blank, not NULL, and he doesn't know how to.

Comment: @Kusalananda - There is no such thing as a "blank" numeric value, it is either an actual number (e.g., `0`) or `Null` (if the column is not "Required"). BTW, Rene, `""` doesn't work for numeric fields.

Comment: I know Gord, apparently my mind was somewhere else today, thanks for clarying though.

Comment: I mean to have the Default Value blank, therefore the default would be Null. But I'm looking to make it that whenever I create a new Number field in any database and any table, rather than deleting the 0.

Comment: As said before, the only way is to change the default value yourself manually.

Comment: @Rene Thanks for updating your answer. It came up in a "low quality" review for me (based on "its length or contents"), hence my previous comment. We'd like to have answers that explains.

Comment: @Rene, sorry. Questions and answers undergo review. Off-topic or duplicate questions gets deleted. Answers with low quality, or that are just plainly missing the point, are also deleted. This process is manual. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161390/what-are-the-review-queues-and-how-do-they-work  Your answer was in the "Low Quality Posts" review queue. I hope that explains it.

Comment: @Kusalananda, then you should delete this comment "He'd like to change it to a blank, not NULL, and he doesn't know how to" too as it's pretty low quality (actually, far lowe quality then my first comment that got deleted)....